# Is there any Angular event on mat-table when table rendering is finished?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9, angular-material-table

I'm looking for an event what is fired when the Angular Material table (mat-table) rendering is finished.

I think it's need to fire on data source is changed, or the user changed the displayed columns or paginate event happend (but it's the same the data source is changed), or any other event happend what is occours a rerendering event.

I tried the generic `ngOnChanges` but it's not fireing when user change the displayed columns.

Is there any similar event what I can listen?

Comment: I don't think there  is (https://material.angular.io/components/table/api). What's your use case?

Comment: @David I just added a custom solution to the tables what give option to the user to resize columns horizontally. I added divs to `th` & `td` tags to give a handle to the user to resize action. But if the user change the visible columns my divs are gone. If the use change datas in thable and the table height is changed, my divs need to be refreshed...

Comment: Check if this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63493607/4233941

Comment: There is an old but still open github feature request: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8068. Also you may have a time shift between component model change and completed DOM rendering.

Answer (score 4):

As of August 2021, you can use the [`contentChanged`](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTable) output property:

```js
<mat-table #matTable
           [dataSource]="tableDatasource"
           (contentChanged)="hideLoader()" <--
>
...
```

Here's the [related, merged PR](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/22750).